# Imprimir BSON do MongoDB com varias estruturas diferentes

Tags: javascript, python, json, mongodb

Estou fazendo uma aplicação usando Python (Flask) e MongoDB.
Nesta aplicação o usuário pode montar sua página inserindo Imagens, Texto ou link do Youtube. Com a sequência que desejar.

Esta primeira parte eu fiz e estou gravando no MongoDB. O Problema está na hora de retornar estes dados, pois cada Documento, fica com uma estrutura diferente do outro, como abaixo:

Exemplo 1:

```
    {
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5afb6dbaee348620405e9844"
    },
    "texto1": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
    "texto2": "Lorem ipsum dolor ",
    "url_video1": "https://youtu.be/5b_eM9ee",
    "img1": "imagem_01.jpg",
    "url_video2": "https://youtu.be/5b_eM9lGPP8"
    "texto3": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur",
    "img2": "imagem_02.jpg" 
}
```

Exemplo 2:

```
    {
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "ee4243g55676j87875afb6dba"
    },
    "texto1": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
    "url_video1": "https://youtu.be/5b_eM9ee",
    "img1": "imagem_01.jpg",
    "texto2": "Lorem ipsum dolor ",
    "img2": "imagem_02.jpg",        
    "url_video2": "https://youtu.be/5b_eM9lGPP8",
    "texto3": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur"        
}
```

Eu consigo trazer todo o *JSON*, e jogar no HTML, o problema é que não estou sabendo como inserir cada item dentro do HTML correspondente:
Quando for texto?? em um `<textarea>`, quando for img?? em um `<img>` e assim por diante, para montar a página na sequência que o usuário criou.

Talvez tenha que trabalhar o *JSON* com JavaScript?
Qual a melhor solução?

Answer (score 1):

Tanto o JSON quanto seu "irmão", o BSON, não preservam a ordem das chaves dentro no documento. A solução mais simples é você armazená-los dentro de um *array*, algo mais ou menos assim:

```
{
    "_id" : { ... },
    "media": [
        { "type": "text", "content": "...", },
        { "type": "video", "url": "https://www.youtube.com/" },
        { "type": "image", "filename": "image.jpeg" },
     ]
 }
```

Aliás a sugestão das chaves "type" para identificar o tipo do documento é opcional, mas creio que vá te ajudar a fazer uma rotina mais simples pra saber o que está armazenado em cada elemento do *array*.

Comment: Obrigado pelo comentário.
Mas mesmo assim, não vejo como identificar a sequência, do tipo de dado que estou recebendo. Vou tentar usar o array e fazer alguns testes.

Obrigado!

Comment: como você cria os dados para enviar ao servidor? 
Anexe uma outra chave lá para dizer o tipo de dados. 

JSON armazena dados, mas tem isso de ter só uma "foto" dos dados em si - se você precisa de mais informações sobre os dados, por exemplo, o tipo, tem que colocar mais informações no próprio json para descreve-los.

Comment: @jsbueno vou trabalhar nessa inclusão de uma chave no momento de gerar os dados usando Angular, e com essa chave conseguir identificar os dados. Obrigado!